# Directus users permission for table

Tags: usergroups, directus

I found some problems with user permissions.

1. **Version Info:** Directus version and branch (Or commit hash): Docker File getdirectus/directus 6.4
2. **PHP version:** 7.1.17
3. **MySQL version:** 5.5
4. **Web server:** (Ex. Apache, nginx or IIS?)
5. **OS name and version:** centOS 7

Expected Behavior:
I expect that a user of a group can only see their own records in the tables, according to group permissions.

- User A of group 1 can not see records of table X created by user B of
  group 2.
- Inoltre l'utente A del gruppo 1 non può vedere i record della tabella
  X creati dall'utente B del gruppo 1

Actual Behaviour:

- User A of group 1 sees the records of table X created by user B of
  group 2.
- User A of group 1 sees the records of table X created by user B of
  group 1

Screenshots
Screenshots of group A permissions on 3 tables, in my case the table activity = X.
The same permissions have been set for group B

[image: screenshot of permissions table]

Answer (score 1):

I solved by setting the 'User Created' field for the tables I want to filter by user